# /(\S)\1(\1)+/g matching all occurrences of three equal non-whitespace characters following each other

Tags: javascript, regex

Its given: /(\S)\1(\1)+/g matches all occurrences of three equal non-whitespace characters following each other.

I don't understand why there is () around (\S) and 2nd (\1), but not around 1st (\1). Can anyone help in explaining how above regex works?

src: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Thnx in advance.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with javascript regex, but the (\1)+ in `/(\S)\1(\1)+/g` means 1 or more, but maybe the `+` after \1+ is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second set of parentheses is not necessary.  It needlessly captures the repeated character a second time, while matching the same strings as this regex:

```
/(\S)\1\1+/g
```

Also, as @AlexD pointed out, the description should say that it matches **at least** three characters.  If you replaced that regex with `BONK` in the string `fooxxxxxxbar`:

```
'fooxxxxxxbar'.replace(/(\S)\1\1+/g, 'BONK')
```

..you might expect the result to be `fooBONKBONKbar` from their description, because there are two sets of three 'x's.  But in fact the result would be `fooBONKbar`; the first `\1` matches the second 'x', and the `\1+` matches the third 'x' *and any 'x's that follow it*.  If they wanted to match just three characters, they should have left the `+` off.

I noticed several other sloppy descriptions like that, plus at least one outright error: `\B` is equivalent to `(?!\b)` (a position that's not a word boundary), not `[^\b]` (a character that's not a backspace).  For that matter, their description of word boundaries--"the position between a word and a space"--is wrong, too.  A word boundary isn't defined by any particular character, like a space--in fact, it can just as well be the absence of *any* character that creates one.  The string:

```
Word
```

...starts with a word boundary because 'W' is a word character and, being first, it's not preceded by another word character.  Similarly, the 'd' is not followed by another word character, so the end of the string is also a word boundary.

Also, a regex doesn't know from *words*, only word *characters*.  The definition of a word character can vary depending on the regex flavor and Unicode or locale settings, but it always includes `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (ASCII letters and digits plus the underscore).  A word boundary is simply a position that's between one of those characters and any other character (or *no* other character, as I explained earlier).

If you want to learn about regexes, I suggest you forget that site and start here instead: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 3):

The `\S` needs parentheses to capture its value, so you can refer back to the captured value with `\1`. `\1` means "match the same text which capturing group #1 matched".

I believe there is a problem with this regex. You said you want to match "three equal non-whitespace characters". But the `+` will make this match 3 *or more* equal, consecutive non-whitespace characters.

The `g` on the end means "apply this regex over the entire input string, or *globally*".